# ng-class, how do I write multiple conditions as true?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

These did not work:

```
ng-class="{'active':user.nav=='mgmt' || 'active':user.nav=='admin'}"
ng-class="{'active':user.nav=='mgmt' || 'admin'}"
ng-class="{active:user.nav=='mgmt'' || 'admin'}"
ng-class="{active:user.nav=='mgmt' , active:user.nav=='admin'}"
```

These do work on their own:

```
ng-class="{active:user.nav=='mgmt'}"
ng-class="{active:user.nav=='admin'}"
```

The use case, I have a sub menu, which is where the ng-classes are working, that when any of the sub items are active, I want the menu dropdown button to appear active too. This will let the end user know generally where they are in the system.

I am new to Angular (3 weeks in), but I am at a new position that uses Angular heavily, so I'm trying to jump in running, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you missed to define `$scope.user = {}` inside controller, non working expression must throwing error in console

Comment: `"{'active': (user.nav=='mgmt' || user.nav=='admin')}"`

Comment: $scope.user = {} seems to be in all relevant controllers, seeing the two at the bottom work perfectly on their own. How would that make the OR statement not function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think instead of

```
ng-class="{'active':user.nav=='mgmt' || 'active':user.nav=='admin'}"
```

this might work

```
ng-class="{'active':user.nav=='mgmt' || user.nav=='admin'}"
```

Comment: This worked, in 6 minutes I am allowed to come back and accept it. Thanks so much!